# Exchange 2010 in different ad sites

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

We have the following situation: a number of servers in head office (Russia) with domain controller and exchange server, and a number of servers in Germany, also with domain controller and exchange server. Cross site replication between DC1 and DC2 is set up (DC1 is primary, it has all 5 roles plus Global Catalog, DC2 is secondary, it has only 3 roles plus Global Catalog).
Exchange servers have identical configuration: Mailbox DB, Hub Transport and Client Access. Receive connectors are set up between it.

```
+---------------------+                    +---------------------+
|   Russia, site 1    |                    |   Germany, site 2   |
+---------------------+                    +---------------------+
| Domain Controller 1 |<--InterSite link-->| Domain Controller 2 |
| Exchange server 1   |                    | Exchange server 2   |
+---------------------+                    +---------------------+
```

While we have all mailboxes on primary exchange server, everything works fine; the problem rises when we want to transfer some mailboxes (in the future - all) to secondary exchange server by Local Move Request in Exchange Server.

When user logs on DC1 (from site 1) and opens Outlook trying to access its mailbox on exchange server 2, he gets the following error message:

> Outlook cannot log on. Verify you are connected to the network and are using the proper server and mailbox name. The connection to Microsoft Exchange is unavailable. Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action.

All three users's attributes indicate to Exchange Server 2

The mailbox is stored in secondary exchange server (in site 2):

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\testtex2> Get-MailboxDatabase | fl name,*rpc*

Name                  : Mailbox Database 0209333681
RpcClientAccessServer : EX1.domain.local

Name                  : Terminal
RpcClientAccessServer : EX1.domain.local

Name                  : RecoveryDB
RpcClientAccessServer : EX1.domain.local

Name                  : DisabledMailboxes
RpcClientAccessServer : EX1.domain.local

Name                  : Terminal-tex2
RpcClientAccessServer : EX2.domain.local

Name                  : Mailbox Database 0785601537
RpcClientAccessServer : EX2.domain.local
```

Software versions:

- Windows Server 2008r2
- Exchange Server 2010SP1

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `"All three users's attributes indicate to Exchange Server"`, please?  It sounds an awful lot like the user's Outlook client is still configured to connect to the old server, or at least, not the new server.

Comment: By user's attributes I mean the following attributes in AD: msExchHomeServerName, homeMDB, homeMTA.
Before moving mailbox  they pointed to EX1, after that were updated to point to EX2.

Comment: So, are you using auto-configuration?  And have you made any changes to the users' Outlook profiles?  Like I said before, it sounds like Outlook is still configured to connect to the old Exchange server.  Create a new profile, point it at the new Exchange server and see if that works.  Let us know.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are transferring mailboxes by "by editing user attributes in active directory", can I confirm you are not using the Exchange 2010 mailbox move request functionality?   If you are hacking stuff in AD without using the provided tools, then the results may not be predictable :-)

Comment: Mailbox was transferred via Mailbox Move Request.
After that user attributes in AD were updated to point to the mailbox on the secondary exchange server.

Comment: The Mailbox Move Request should update the relevant AD attributes as part of the process.  msExchHomeServerName and HomeMTA are no longer used by Exchange 2010 - http://blogs.technet.com/b/timmcmic/archive/2011/09/26/exchange-2010-homemta-and-msexchhomeservername-are-not-updated-on-mailboxes.aspx

Comment: I suppose, but the attribute values​have changed as a result of staff movements